# jquery change event not firing in pop up

Tags: jquery

I have a standard jquery Mobile popUp which contains a form in it:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="costCentreClientEditPopup">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="b">Close</a>
    <form id="costCentreClientEditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="jqm-block-content">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><select name="areaLevelOneID"      id="int_areaLevelOneID"></select></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><select name="areaLevelTwoID" id="int_areaLevelTwoID"></select></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><select name="costCentreClientClassID" id="int_costCentreClientClassID" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Select Activity:</option><option value="0"></option></select></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="costCentreClientGroupIDDiv">
                        <select name="costCentreClientGroupID" id="int_costCentreClientGroupID">
                          <option value="0">No Group</option></select>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="str_firstName">name:</label><input type="text" value="" name="firstName" id="str_firstName" /></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="str_surname">surname:</label><input type="text" value="" name="surname" id="str_surname" /></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                            <legend>male:</legend>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="bool_gender" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="jqm-block-content">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="int_cellNumber">cell n&deg;</label><input type="text" name="cellNumber" id="int_cellNumber" /></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="ageDiv"><label for="int_age">age:</label><input type="text" width="40px" name="age" id="int_age" /></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><select name="costCentreClientIDClassID" id="int_costCentreClientIDClassID"></select></div>
                    <div id="costCentreClientIDDiv">    
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="str_costCentreClientID">ID:</label><input type="text" name="costCentreClientID" id="str_costCentreClientID" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dateHolder">
                        <div id="participantTrainingDate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pageInfoImageDiv">
                        <div id="pageInfoTextDiv"></div>
                    </div>    
                    <button id="costCentreClientDataInsertButton" class="ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>   
    </form>
    </div><!-- end of popUp -->
```

Both Int_areaLevelOne and int_areaLevelTwo have change events attached

```
 $('#int_areaLevelOneID').on("change", function(event){
    $('#int_areaLevelTwoID').empty();
    $(xmlDoc).find('areaLevelTwo').each(function(){
        $(this).find('entity').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("int_areaLevelOneID")==$('#int_areaLevelOneID').val()){
                $('#int_areaLevelTwoID').append($('<option></option>').val($(this).attr("int_entityID")).html($(this).text()));
                }
            });
        }); 
    $("#int_areaLevelTwoID").val($("#int_areaLevelTwoID option:first").val()).change();
    });

  $('#int_areaLevelTwoID').on("change", function(event){
    $('#int_costCentreClientGroupID').empty();
    $('#int_costCentreClientGroupID').append($('<option></option>').val(0).html('No Sector'));
    $(xmlDoc).find('costCentreClientGroups').each(function(){
        $(this).find('entity').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("int_costCentreAreaID") == $('#int_areaLevelTwoID').val()){
                $('#int_costCentreClientGroupID').append($('<option></option>').val($(this).attr("int_entityID")).html($(this).text()));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Both these events fire when triggered on

```
$(window.document).ready(function(){.....
 ....
$("#int_areaLevelOneID").val($("#int_areaLevelOneID option:first").val()).change();
$("#int_areaLevelTwoID").val($("#int_areaLevelTwoID option:first").val()).change();
});
```

But neither of these events will fire within the pop up either

```
popupbeforeopen: function(event, ui){ 
    $("int_areaLevelOneID").val($("#dataSetTwoDiv").find(".entitySelected").attr("id")).change();
                                       $("int_areaLevelTwoID").val(int_areaLevelTwoID).change();        
}
 where $("#dataSetTwoDiv").find(".entitySelected").attr("id") and int_areaLevelTwoID are both integers.
```

or

```
popupafteropen: function(event, ui){ 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this peace of code between normal logic  and popup specific logic

```
$("div#costCentreClientEditPopup").off();
```

this disabled all event in popup element already specified and after that you can add new event logic

or if you need to change elements logic according to popup visibility then add something like if-else statement to event listener function

Comment: Thanks I tried that and in fact tried to code it so the logic was created within the popup element but still does not work.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Both change events were missing # so  $("#int_areaLevelTwoID").val(int_areaLevelTwoID).change();

Comment: I think better to use trigger("change") instead of change();